# How to redirect user to Android Market in Apache?

Tags: apache-httpd, mod-rewrite

On my website I should redirect Android users to my application on Android Market.
What is the optimal way to do this?
My first idea was

```
       RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  Android [NC]
       RewriteRule ^/$         market://details?id=......
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: While this question is on-topic here as long as you're running Apache on a unix system, you'll find more Apache experts on [webmasters.se]. Don't repost: if you like, a moderator can migrate your question there (use the `flag` button to request a migration).

Answer (score 1):

Just redirect to `https://market.android.com/details?id=...`; the Market application is set up as a handler for those URLs.

Comment: I already tried http[s]://market... - in this case android device asks if user want to continue using browser or market.
And I want to sent user directly to market using market app.